# cakephp2 beginner: how to compare the data from the db with a integer?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I want to compare a data from the db in cakephp2.
For example I have a data $product['price'], this data contains a value of 0.
I want to compare it with integers like the source code below, however,I cannot compare them.
I would love to have some help.

```
if($product['price']==0){
     echo "free";
   }else{
     echo "$".$product['price'];
   }
```

Comment: `var_dump($product['price']);` above your if condition and let us know its value

Comment: string(1) "0"　is the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your var_dump of $product['price'] shows it is a string you need to convert it to an integer first - use

```
if (intval($product['price']) == 0) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

If possible though, it would be better to change your actual database so that the field you're looking at is an integer to begin with (stops someone saving a price as "SomeRandomLetters" instead ;)